# How to format the name of the SQL Server 2008 backup file?

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008

I define a backup task form the SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. The task creates backup files with name db_backup_YYYY_MM_DD_HHMMSS_ID.bak

Is there a way to change the format. I'm interestet of the weekday db_backup_weekday.bak

Comment: IMHO the format you proposed is far less informative than the default. I assume you want rotate the backups but belive me - something's gonna fail and you won't even notice that backups are not being made.

Comment: The date/time format is a little bit redundant when the same is on the timestamp for local files. Anyway i was thinking in a program (Studio) with so much options. maybe i could'nt find/see the option for the filename format ...

Comment: Actually it is not - you  can not select / copy / open files by timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that you can do this via a maintenace plan.  You will probably be able to do this if you write your backup via a script.